# Automatically adding post and pages to new blog setups

Tags: plugins, multisite, pages, blog-page, clone-site

I'm using the [ThreeWP Broadcast](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/threewp-broadcast/) plugin to add and control post and pages from the main blog to all my sub-blogs in the network. Is there anyway i can automatically add all of my post and pages from my main blog to new blogs I set up without having to go in each individual post and page and adding it manually?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the export feature to export the posts. Go to Tools>Export and choose WordPress. You will be prompted to add a plug-in at when you import it into the other sites. Just click install plug-in at the screen that pops up. You can then upload the XML file that you generated by exporting the original posts. At import you will have the option to import users or switch them to an existing user, and whether or not to download attachments.